# readOnly text field will show a box in edit mode

Tags: jsgrid

When I go into edit mode, my readOnly text field is shown with an input box, even though it is disabled from any editing.

Is it possible not to show the box as it is misleading to the user?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should override the default [editTemplate](http://js-grid.com/docs/#fields) for your field so it just returns the text, not an input that is disabled.

Answer (score 2):

You can 'editing' to false for field.
For example 'Link' will be auto-generated field and you don't want to see input:

```
fields: [
    { name: "Name", type: "text", width: 150 },
    { name: "Description", type: "text", width: 150, validate: "required" },
    { name: "Link", type: "text", width: 150, editing: false },
    { type: "control" }
]
```

Please, read [documentation](http://js-grid.com/docs/#control) for more info

Comment: You also can use 'inserting' equals to false to disable inserting.